# How can i turn these into groups of 4 instep of 2?

Tags: php

So this is my code it takes a list o people from the database and lists them with their partners in groups. Within these groups, the user id of the people cannot appear in the same row twice. Everything works, Im just wondering how to make it echo 4 people per group versus only 2.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM performers")) {
printf("Found %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

$rows = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $col) {
        unset($row[$key]);
        $row[strtolower($key)] = $col;
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
}

$current = null;
$count = 1;
while ( ! empty($rows)) {
    if ($current) {
        $current_performers = array($current['performerid_1'], $current['performerid_2']);
        $found = false;
        foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
            if ( ! in_array($row['performerid_1'], $current_performers) && ! in_array($row['performerid_2'], $current_performers)) {
                $found = $key;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($found !== false) {
            echo '<li>', $rows[$found]['performance_id'], ': ', $rows[$found]['perf_name_1'], ' - ', $rows[$found]['perf_name_2'], '</li>';
            unset($rows[$key]);


        }

        else {
            echo '';
        }

        echo '</ul><hr />';

        $current = null;
    } else {
        $current = array_shift($rows);
        echo '<h3>Group ', $count+,  '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>', $current['performance_id'], ': ', $current['perf_name_1'], ' - ', $current['perf_name_2'], '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean two partnerships, or do you mean that the partnerships are replaced with teams of 4?

Comment: Lets say you had 9 entries( 1 entry is 1 partnership, 2 people). Id be looking to have 3 groups each containing 3 entries where within those groups none of the individual id's can be duplicates.

Comment: I thought you said groups of 4, not 3.

Comment: 4 works, three is just an example given the number of entries i used (9)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it, but I haven't tested it (except to verify syntax) because I don't have any sample data.

```
$group_size = 4;
$current_performers = array();
$current_size = 0;
$count = 1;
while (!empty($rows)) {
    if ($current_size == $group_size) { // End previous group
        echo '</ul><hr>';
        $current_performers = array();
        $current_size = 0;
    }
    if ($current_size == 0) {
        echo '<h3>Group ', $count++,  '</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    $found = false;
    foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
        if ( ! in_array($row['performerid_1'], $current_performers) && ! in_array($row['performerid_2'], $current_performers)) {
            $found = true;
            array_push($current_performers, $row['performerid_1'], $row['performerid_2']);
            $current_size++;
            echo '<li>', $row['performance_id'], ': ', $row['perf_name_1'], ' - ', $row['perf_name_2'], '</li>';
            unset($rows[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!$found) {
        // Force a new group to start
        $current_size = $group_size;
    }
    // If we have an unfinished group, finish it
    if ($current_size) {
        echo '</ul><hr>';
    }

}
```

Comment: I removed my code after the query and added your code but wasn't able to get anything, All that shows up is a found 18 rows followed but blank space.

Comment: What debugging have you done to try to get it working? Like I said, I wasn't able to test it because I don't have any data.

Comment: I used a dtabase with 18 rows and columns that match the information thats written above, I removed my code after the query and put yours in. Is there any other way that I should try?

Comment: I'm not going to make a database of my own. Can you update your question with `$rows = array(....)` and the data, so I can do this?

Comment: can I export the database and send it to you, the reason being because im not sure how to insert the data in the way youre asking.

Comment: Use `var_export($rows)` and add it to the question.